# Do I write "I wonder why I exist" or "I wonder why do I exist"?

Tags: grammaticality, usage, inversion

As the title says, do I write "I wonder why I exist" or "I wonder why do I exist"?
 In this case, I am not expecting an answer, if that makes any difference.

If I were to ask someone, I would write (say) "why do I exist?", but what about in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: You're pondering your very existence and the question foremost in your mind is whether the sentence should include "do"?

Comment: You are thus you exist!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "do" is called a *do-support*, it is needed when you convert a declarative (statement) clause that doesn't have any auxiliary into an interrogative (question) clause, as in

> Declarative : I exist (no auxiliary) 
>   Intterogative : Why do I exist? (*do* is added)

But it is not needed when the question in **embedded** in another clause.

> I wonder **why I exist**?

Comment: But it could be:  I wonder, “Why do I exist?”

Comment: @Jim Yes, but I think that's a horse of a different color. :)

Comment: "I wonder why I do exist" has a nice iambic rhythm. You could start a poem with it and nobody would think it odd. Or you could playfully pretend to start a poem with it.

Answer (score 0):

*I wonder why do I exist* needs at least a comma, if not a colon.

*I wonder, why do I exist*

*I wonder: why do I exist*